# Adding a top navigation bar in a html page with a 100% high css element

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to add a navigation bar in my html template but it gets covered by the map which has height = 100%.
This is my map style:

```css
#windyty {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap-3.3.6.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/font-awesome-4.7.0.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap-social-4.12.0.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-4.17.37.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/jquery.dataTables-1.10.12.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/buttons.dataTables-1.2.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/buttons.bootstrap-1.2.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/leaflet-0.7.7.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/leaflet.extra-markers.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/easy-button.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/leaflet-sidebar.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/styles-min-20170519174922.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/0.4.0/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>


<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="windyty"></div>
```

ce that my navigation bar still exists but it's covered by the map. How can I do to add a navigation bar which is always visible? I am new to coding so sorry if this is trivial.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I assume windyty is where the image is located. You have positioned it absolutely which in this case means it will always be located at the top/left of the window. Make it a background image of windyty and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks. Windyty is an interactive map showing weather forecasts and i would like my page to contain a navbar and the map!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the code of fixed navigation bar.
 Changes are:1)remove windyty as absolute 2) make ul tag as fixed

```css
#windyty {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="windyty">
  <h1>abcdef</h1>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

Hope this link helps you in making a fixed navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks, but I would like my windyty object to **start** just after (without overlapping) the navigation bar. Windyty is a map so I don't want to allow the nav bar to cover it. Is it possible?

Comment: Use margin-top property to windyty for not overlapping with the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  background:url("UR URL") no-repeat center center;
  background-size:cover; 
}
```

This will have the background behind the nav.

```css
#windyty {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

body {
  background: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/polygonal-blue-background-with-lights_1035-6712.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="windyty">
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
    <p>MY PAGE</p>
  </div>

</body>
```